# How can a Python function create a global object with a name defined in an argument of that function?

Tags: python, function, variables, module, global

I want to have a Python function create a global object such that the name of this global object is a name specified as an argument of the function. I know how to create a global object in a function, but I do not know how to create it with a variable name.

```
def function1():
    global foo
    foo = 3

def function2(nameOfObject):
    exec("global " + nameOfObject)
    bar = 4

function1()
print foo
function2("bar")
print bar
```

The actual use of this type of function shall be to create a global module object and the function shall be used multiple times. Note that I do not want to create an object in the function and then return it to an existing global object.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? How do you plan on using the side-effect? Doing such things is often considered a very poor programming practice and normally should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `globals`

```
def foo(name, val): 
    globals()[name] = val
```

Comment: @d3pd: This isn't doing what you asked for in your question.